# Access search results object in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am implementing google tag manager on a Magento store and I need to add a tag in the datalayer for the search term and the number of search results.

I can get the search text using:

```
Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the number of results returned. I have tried using

```
$search = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->getProductCollection();
```

But that does not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that allowed me to get the search results collection.

```
    $term = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/query_collection')->setQueryFilter($term)->getData();
    $results = $collection[0]['num_results'];
    return json_encode($results);
```

Comment: I am not sure if your method loads the entire collection or not. You don't want to load the whole thing if all you need is the size. Did you try `$collection[0]->getSize()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$size = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->getProductCollection()->getSize();
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that there is a magento stackexchange site that could help you for future questions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That returns 107 which I believe is all simple products in my catalog (113 total products - 6 configurable = 107). Can I filter the collection based on search term?

Comment: I haven't used search to create a collection, I have just filtered on the attributes I want in the collection. But if your code IS returning a product collection, then getSize should work. Are you sure 107 is not the expected number? Where is the search term?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what the search term will be. Looking at toolbar.phtml I see the call for `$this->getTotalNum())` which in toolbar.php calls `    public function getTotalNum()
    {
        return $this->getCollection()->getSize();
    }`  the correct number. How do I access $this outside of that block?

Comment: Don't bother going to Magento StackExchange site. It has low to null support, specially on important features like this one. The main StackOverflow site has a broader magento community.